# How to assign resultSet to global variable to use output of one method in another method in java

Tags: java, jdbc, playframework, resultset

I am trying to store the output value of one method in a global variable so that i can use that value in another method. I code in java with play framework.

I have method where i need to run a query and the query is a dynamic one it is generated based on the filter conditions from user request.

I wish to save the resultSet in the first method so that i can use that resultSet data in the next method.

```
resultSet queryData;
public String list() {
    connection = "";
    resultSet data;
    query ="";
    data = this.Execute(query,connection);
    return "data";
}
public byte[] dataList() {
    connection = "";
    while(queryData.next()){
        xyz;
    }
}
```

This is a sample of my code i have similar to this.

In my first method the query is executed and the resultSet is assigned to variable data.

I would like to store it in queryData global variable and use that in the next method.

Is there a way to do so?
Pls help

Comment: Have you tried to do it (with proper class name `ResultSet`)?

Comment: Software developers experienced within last 40 years that **global variables are eval**, especially in OO programming. **Don't do that!** Return that list as the methods return value and call it from the method, that needs wo work with the data.

Answer (score -1):

If your local variable `data` in `list` method is returned, then I don't understand why you need global variable to store it? You can call it in your next method, and store it in a local variable there??

For example:

```
public ResultSet list() {
    connection = "";
    ResultSet data;
    query ="";
    data = this.Execute(query,connection);
    return data;
}
public byte[] dataList() {
    ResultSet data = list();
    connection = "";
    while(data.next()){
        xyz;
    }
}
```

Comment: `list` is defined to return a String